# Create a new command that makes a footnote with a custom prefix

Tags: macros, footnotes

New to macros here, I need to be able to create a document with the regular footnote commands and a custom command that makes footnotes work identically to the regular one but add a prefix ''R'' before (stands for remarks).

Comment: Where should this `R` appear: Before the footnote number at the footer?

Comment: Yes that is it. It should look something like this: R1 (insert footnote text here).

Comment: You could use the package [manyfoot](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/ncctools/doc/manyfoot.pdf). In page 4 you can find how to define a new footnote.

Comment: Should the "R"-styled footnotes use the same number sequence that the normal one or should be independent?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a package named `manyfoot` which can be used to create new type of footnotes along with the default footnote. The following code will show how to define a new footnote:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{manyfoot}

\DeclareNewFootnote{A}
\DeclareNewFootnote{B}
\renewcommand\thefootnoteB{R\arabic{footnoteB}}
\let\footnoteR\footnoteB
\let\footnote\footnoteA
\begin{document}

Test\footnote{Regular footnote.} and Remark\footnoteR{Remark footnote}.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Using no particular package, just 'hacking' the usual definitions of `latex.ltx` and `article.cls` (for example)

```
\documentclass{article}


\makeatletter

\newcommand{\myfootnoteprefix}{R}

\newcommand\@makeremfntext[1]{%
  \parindent 1em%
  \noindent
  \hb@xt@1.8em{\hss\myfootnoteprefix\@makeremfnmark}: #1}% Prevent raised footnote number here with \@makeremfnmark


\def\@makeremfnmark{\hbox{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}% No \@textsuperscript!

\def\remfootnote{\@ifnextchar[\@xfootnote{\stepcounter\@mpfn
     \protected@xdef\@thefnmark{\thempfn}%
     \@footnotemark\@remfootnotetext}}
 \long\def\@remfootnotetext#1{\insert\footins{%
     \reset@font\footnotesize
     \interlinepenalty\interfootnotelinepenalty
     \splittopskip\footnotesep
     \splitmaxdepth \dp\strutbox \floatingpenalty \@MM
     \hsize\columnwidth \@parboxrestore
     \protected@edef\@currentlabel{%
       \csname p@footnote\endcsname\@thefnmark
     }%
     \color@begingroup% Use `\@makeremfntext instead of \@makefntext
     \@makeremfntext{%
       \rule\z@\footnotesep\ignorespaces#1\@finalstrut\strutbox}%
     \color@endgroup}}%


 \makeatother


\begin{document}
Some footnote\remfootnote{Hello}

Some other footnote\remfootnote{Hello again!}
\end{document}
```

[image]